# Error while reindexing on Solr - RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request - undefined field type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, solr4, sunspot-solr

I have setup Solr 4.4 on Ubuntu server with Tomcat 6 following this link - http://www.arborisoft.com/how-to-install-apache-solr-4-4-on-ubuntu-12-04/.

Model Activity is indexed using Solr (Ruby on Rails project). While reindexing, I get this error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: {'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>400,'QTime'=>59},'error'=>{'msg'=>'undefined field type','code'=>400}}

URI: http://localhost:8080/solr/update?wt=ruby
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}
Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Activity</query></delete>"

Backtrace: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:284:in `adapt_response'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in `update'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:146:in `delete_by_query'(eval):2:in `post'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

sunspot.yml

```
staging:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8080
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/
```

Comment: check if you have config files under the conf folder...schema.xml and solrconfig.xml...http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/example/solr/conf/

Comment: conf files are in /opt/solr/collection1/conf/ directory as mentioned in this tutorial - http://www.arborisoft.com/how-to-install-apache-solr-4-4-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: do you have sunspot.yml file ?

Comment: Is it something to do with the solr version? It works with my local server. There I have Solr 4.1 configured. I set up staging server with solr 4.4.

Comment: you have not mentioned the collection name in sunspot.yml at path : /solr/collection_name

Comment: Tried adding collection name to sunspot.yml. It gives the same error.

Comment: can you paste the change here

Comment: Thanks but changing sunspot.yml doesn't help. If sunspot.yml was incorrect, then solr server wouldn't have started. (Believe me, I've spent a lot of time in getting the configuration right). The issue here seems to be with the solr version. It seems that Solr 4.4 doesn't support some data type.

Comment: open the schema.xml and check if you have 'msg' field type defined there...

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to reindex now. schema.xml had this line missing:

```
<field name="type" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```